# return struct from .net dll (C#)

Tags: matlab

I have a .net DLL (C#) that receives real-time (and lots) of data over TCP from a sensor. The data is coming as arrays of custom objects. (call it a SensorPacket, that has about 20 fields, mostly float and int).

I have been sending this up to matlab via events (works fine). But Matlab sees them as an array of .NET objects. I would prefer to send this up as a array of struct. How?

yes, one can convert this array to a cell array via:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/net-arrays-to-cell-arrays.html

but that still leaves this as a cell array of .net objects. Can one cast the objects so that I can get the values?

and better would be to send a cell/array of struct.

I had tried converting this to JSON, and using a matlab JSON reader to convert to structs, but this is very very slow: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files

Don't laugh, but I am thinking of using the DLL to write a .MAT file, and then send up the handle to that to Matlab. This writer might work: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319-csmatio--mat-file-i-o-api-for-net-2-0

In the following page, it says I can return a struct or a class, but my experience is that this returns a System.Object

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-net-data-in-matlab_bte9owt-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that unlike plain-C, mex files, you cannot return matlab native structs and object. But you can return a C# object of a class you define, and you can access the properties from Matlab (just do a properties(netObj) and you will see then. True, you will see a System.String[] for strings, but that can be fixed by doing a char() on the object. Most others scalars also work.

In my case, I am getting JSON messages via SingnalR, converting them to an ExpandDo object, then creating the individual class objects, and sending EVENTS to matlab. This all works, and is 20X faster than having the Matlab parse the JSON. but still a little slow for real bulk work. I am now starting on using the csmatio tools (https://sourceforge.net/projects/csmatio )to write a .MAT file, and then I will signal Matlab that the data is ready for it.

But below you can see my C# code for how I am doing it write now: (note, you can just create .NET events) and they will show up in Matlab just like any Matlab events, and pass the values as arguments! I do the task.invoke to keep the thread in .NET from hanging while matlab processes the data.

```
    public delegate void PostPerson(Portal sender, dynamic e);
    public event PostPerson Post;

        private void deliver(dynamic packet)
    {
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(packet.ToString(), converter);
        dynamic mail;
        String channelName = (string)data.Channel;
        switch (channelName)
        {
            case "Oxford":
                mail = new Oxford(data);
                break;
            case "RADAR":
                mail = new Radar(data);
                break;
            case "SVSRear":
                mail = new SVS(data);
                break;
            case "SVSFront":
                mail = new SVS(data);
                break;
            case "IBEO":
                mail = new IBEO(data);
                break;
            case "Fusion":
                mail = new Fusion(data);
                break;
            default:
                postFail(String.Format("Portal: deliver: Unknown Channel: {0}", channelName));
                return;
        }
        trigger(mail);
    }
    private void trigger(dynamic e)
    {
        if (Post != null)
        {
            //Post(this, e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Post(this, e); });
        }
    }
```