# C# - MATLAB generic interface

Tags: c#, json, matlab

I'm dealing with the exact same case as [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105366/return-struct-from-net-dll-c). I have a MATLAB process which generate information from a sensor (realtime) and I need to pass info to .NET dll, serialize (to JSON) and send. I also need the ability to deserialize JSON in C# and pass it back to MATLAB.

One limitation though - I don't have strict objects that I know I currently need to pass, meaning I need to write something generic.

When receiving JSON, I currently do

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
```

But now, I need a way to cast `data` to types that MATLAB can understand, or find a way for MATLAB to understand `ExpandoObject`.

I tried dealing with `Newtonsoft.JSON`'s object in MATLAB (`JToken`, `JObject`, etc). Couldn't find a way, for example, to access all `JObject`'s keys from MATLAB (in C# it's done using `LINQ`).

Note, `json` can be something like:

```
{
    "a": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
    "b": 8,
    "c": ["aa", "bb", "cc"],
    "d": {
        "da": [1, 2, 4, 8],
        "db": true
    }
}
```

In that case, I would like to end with a MATLAB struct such that:

```
data.a = [1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6;];  % double
data.b = 8;                    % double
data.c = {'aa', 'bb', 'cc'};   % cell
data.d.da = [1, 2, 4, 8];      % double
data.d.db = true;              % logical
```

Comment: Could you just pass the json directly to MATLAB and decode it there? If you have a recent MATLAB (>2016b) you can use the built-in `jsondecode` (some earlier versions have a built-in (but hidden) decoder also).

Comment: I tried using `jsonlab`, which is very slow. I would like dealing with JSON in C# and leave MATLAB to do processing only.

Comment: Well `jsondecode` is a built-in, compiled function in MATLAB - it seems pretty quick to me. E.g. I downloaded this 617KB json file (https://github.com/akrylysov/python-json-benchmark/blob/master/data/twitter.json) and on my system this command `jsondecode( fileread('twitter.json.txt') )` ran in 0.078 sec.

Comment: One thing I can't do with that approach, for instance, is to encode a 1x1 array, as it is encoded as scalar (using `jsonencode`). Generally I will have less control over types.